# How do I layout a list of images + labels I gather from my DB properly inside my Horizontal StackLayout/Scrollview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a two issues with my layout problem.
The first issue is that I am trying to make the Image Aspect.AspectFill but the image does not AspectFill with my current code (they remain with different sizes).

And the second issue is the layout itself.

With my current code what It looks like is this:

```
 <  IMAGE -> IMAGENAME -> LABEL -> IMAGE -> IMAGENAME -> LABEL etc. >
```

And I do not want the IMAGENAME to be shown.

What I want to achieve is this, where the IMAGE is connected with the right LABEL underneath:

```
< IMAGE    IMAGE    IMAGE    IMAGE >
< LABEL    LABEL    LABEL    LABEL >
```

This is the current code that I am working with:

My XAML:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
<StackLayout x:Name = "myStack" Orientation="Horizontal" 
HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

</StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my code:

```
public List <string> imageList = new List<string> ();

async void loadImages ()
{
    var getImages = await phpApi.getImages ();

    foreach (var theitems in getImages ["results"])
    {
        var value = "";
        var valueTwo = "";
        imageList.Add 
        (value = theitems ["Photo"].ToString());

        imageList.Add 
        (valueTwo = theitems ["PhotoName"].ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++) {

        var image = new Image ();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (image, new Rectangle (0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4)); 
            image.Source = imageList [i];
            image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;

            var label = new Label ();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (label, new Rectangle (0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4));
            label.Text = imageList [i];

            myStack.Children.Add (image);
            myStack.Children.Add (label);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> imageList = new Dictionary<string,string> ();

async void loadImages ()
{
    var getImages = await phpApi.getImages ();

    foreach (var theitems in getImages ["results"])
    {
        imageList.Add(
          theitems ["Photo"].ToString(),
          theitems ["PhotoName"].ToString()
        );

    }

    foreach (var key in imageList.Keys) {

        // vertical stack for each image/label pair
        var inner = new StackLayout();

        var image = new Image ();
        image.Source = key;
        image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;

        var label = new Label ();
        label.Text = imageList [key];

        inner.Children.Add(image);
        inner.Children.Add(label);
        myStack.Children.Add (inner);

    }

}
```

Comment: The images gets very wide now and still different sizes. I cannot see the label.text either. I tried to add an `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (image, new Rectangle (0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4));` after `image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;` but seems like it does no difference

Comment: why don't you set a width or height on the image?

Comment: I would like to control it via a absoluteLayout if that is possible somehow. Would I add a <AbsoluteLayout> inside my stacklayout in XAML and replace `myStack.Children.Add (inner);` with `myAbsolute.Children.Add (inner);` maybe?

Comment: Your solution works fine btw! I have a bad experience with heightrequest + widthequet in a stack though because the results gets so different depending on what mobile you are on